# Creating user with API Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how would i go about creating a user inn the database with a api call? Im using the Model.serializer, ive tried to override the save method and create a user with the request.data but i cant seem to get it to work. Any tips? The error that i get is that when i try to asign the user to the request.data it comes back saying that the value needs to be a user instance. How do i make the requested data a user instance? This is my code.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createUser(request):

    serializer = userSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(request.data['username'])

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        if request.data['password'] == request.data['password2']:
            userModel = UserModel.objects.create(
                user=request.data,
                username=request.data['username'],
                email=request.data['email'],
                firstname=request.data['firstname'],
                lastname=request.data['lastname'],
                password=request.data['password'],
                password2=request.data['password2']
            )
            userModel.save()
            return Response('User was created')
        else:
            return Response('Passwords must match')
```

Comment: try `user=request.user`.

Comment: What's `UserModel`? Is it the same as the builtin `User` model? Also why are you saving userModel again right after creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use a ModelViewSet like this

```
class RegisterUser(ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = userSerializer()
  query_set = UserModel.objects.all()
  
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
    password = self.request.data['password']
    password2 = self.request.data['password2']
    if (password==password2):
       serializer.save()
       return Response('User was created')
   else:
      return Response('Password did not match')
```

Then call it in your urls as

```
path("register", views.RegisterUser.as_view()),
```

Comment: thanks man, that looks clean. Il try that, ive sorted out the problem but i liked this code better :D Cheers

Comment: Welcome bro, feel free to let the community know if u come  across other issues.